# Set gridview column width programmatically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, width, set

Need to set the column width of a gridview in asp.net programmatically. 
** Autogenerated Columns (i.e., AutogenerateColumns = "true").

I tried the following;

```
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[2].Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
}
```

but no use.

Comment: I'll answer with what I've done when I needed to set gridview column width programmatically.But I did not have `AutogeneratedColumns=True`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my `GridView1` on aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
Font-Size="Small" Width="800px" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" > 

        <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField SelectText="Seç" ShowSelectButton="True"/>
        </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

This is where I set my GridView's column width programmatically in codebehind.It is actually about setting the cell's width but it controls the column width so this is a way.As you can see I do not have `AutogeneratedColumns="True"`, though I do not think that would matter because `GridView.RowDataBound` occurs when a data row is bound to data.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
     e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 1;
     e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 1;
     e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 75;
     e.Row.Cells[5].Width = 1;                
}
```

Comment: I got ArgumentOutOfRangeException; Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Here is the code ' protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
         e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 200;
        }'

Comment: how are you binding data to your gridview?This event fires when data is bound to your gridview, if you do not have any data bound to it you will get that exception because `e.Row.Cells[number]` will not exist.