# Set gridview's column width

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have gridview as follows:

[image]

But when i enters any larger with text in it, its column with gets increased as follows:

[image]

In this we can see that when i have entered large text English Question column's with has got effected.

I wanted to keep it fix.

For that i added   `<ItemStyle  HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="45%"   />`  in grid's templatefield

but its not working. I also made `wrap="true"` for label. but no effect on result.

For more clarity my whole code for grid is as follows:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GrdQuestions" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        CssClass="NormalText" PageSize="100" Width="100%">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHeadingNormal TableAlt2" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="AltColor21" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltColor22" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SrNo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblQMID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QMId") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="3%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="English Question">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnglish" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("English") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEnglish" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("English") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <%--
                                   <%# Eval("English") %>--%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="45%" Wrap="true" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Spanish Question">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpanish" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Spanish") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSpanish" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Spanish") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <%-- <%#Eval("Spanish")%>--%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="45%" Wrap="true" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                                        Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LBCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                        Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                        Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>'
                                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me.

Comment: @butterbox i tried that things,,i already mentioned it in my question.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980365/set-gridview-column-width-programatically-in-asp-net to?

Comment: @butterbox that is giving me error

Comment: Have you tried templating them with a textblock and setting the wrap property on the text block?

Comment: @Bearcat9425 I done it with label wrap="true"

Comment: Only thing I have read is wrapping that column in a div and applying css to it like so, <div style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 300px;"><%#Eval("DisplayOnIssueSummary") %></div>  I also read in a few places that there is a bug with wrap cause its not valid html.  See here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49d3ecf2-688e-4a4c-99c2-5feb39ed8871/gridview-text-not-wrapping-in-ie8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the `RowStyle-Wrap` property of the `gridview` to True.